# How to run nmap with sudo previlages in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-image, nmap

I've tried installing sudo in my docker image yet nmap reports with no MAC addresses...

I've a docker image which I built using the following command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t ubuntu-docker:tt .
```

and ran the container like this:

```
docker run --network host --name IoT -t -i ubuntu-docker:tt
```

But When I run nmap I've a problem, in my macOS when running nmap without sudo like this:

```
nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24
```

it reports only ips.

To get MAC addresses too I need to modify the command to:

```
sudo nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/24
```

but in my docker container running the last command returns:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

How to fix this?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nmap

CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on MacOS systems (or anything else using Docker Desktop); you won't get an error message, but the network environment also isn't the actual host environment.  If you need to manage the host's network environment you should use native host tools, rather than trying to work inside an isolation environment like Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your base image does not have "sudo" command installed.

Docker images generally do not come with "sudo" command installed for security reasons.

If you wish to run sudo you will first need to install the sudo package as shown in the Dockerfile below.

I have optimized your Dockerfile a bit by removing unnecessary commands and statements.

**Updated Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget nmap sudo

CMD /bin/bash
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker run --network host --name IoT -t -i ubuntu-docker:tt
root@controlplane:/# sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-ABknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-ABknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-ABbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T timeout] [-u
            user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-ABknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T timeout] [-u user]
            file ...
root@controlplane:/# sudo nmap
Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org )
Usage: nmap [Scan Type(s)] [Options] {target specification}
TARGET SPECIFICATION:
    Can pass hostnames, IP addresses, networks, etc.
    Ex: scanme.nmap.org, microsoft.com/24, 192.168.0.1; 10.0.0-255.1-254
    -iL <inputfilename>: Input from list of hosts/networks
    -iR <num hosts>: Choose random targets
    --exclude <host1[,host2][,host3],...>: Exclude hosts/networks
    --excludefile <exclude_file>: Exclude list from file
HOST DISCOVERY:
    -sL: List Scan - simply list targets to scan
    -sn: Ping Scan - disable port scan
    -Pn: Treat all hosts as online -- skip host discovery
    -PS/PA/PU/PY[portlist]: TCP SYN/ACK, UDP or SCTP discovery to given ports
```

Comment: Thanks, yet this doesn't solve my issue, nmap still doesn't report mac addresses even though I ran it as sudo...